# Show $\frac{\pi}{\alpha \sinh (\pi \alpha)} = \sum_{n= -\infty}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\alpha^2 + n^2} $

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, complex-integration, fourier-transform

The question has 2 parts.

First it asks to show that, given $\;f(t) = e^{\alpha t}\;$ on $\;(-\pi, \pi):$

$$
e^{\alpha t} = \frac{\sinh (\pi \alpha)}{\pi} \sum_{n= -\infty}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}}{\alpha^2 + n^2}(\alpha + i n) e^{i n t}
$$

which I did using complex version of Fourier expansion:

$$
f(t) = \sum_{n= -\infty}^\infty c_n e^{i n t}
$$

with

$$
 c_n = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi f(t) e^{-i n t} dt, \quad \forall\; n \in \mathbb{Z}.
$$

Next it asks using the result from first part, to show that

$$
\frac{\pi}{\alpha \sinh (\pi \alpha)} = \sum_{n= -\infty}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{\alpha^2 + n^2}
$$

and that it where I am stuck.

any hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there.  Note that from odd symmetry that

$$\color{blue}{\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n\,n}{n^2+\alpha^2}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1} \frac{(-1)^n\,n}{n^2+\alpha^2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n\,n}{n^2+\alpha^2}=0}$$

Now, setting $t=0$ in the equation

$$e^{\alpha t} = \frac{\sinh (\pi \alpha)}{\pi} \sum_{n= -\infty}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}}{\alpha^2 + n^2}(\alpha + i n) e^{i n t}$$

reveals

$$\begin{align}1 &= \frac{\sinh (\pi \alpha)}{\pi} \sum_{n= -\infty}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}}{\alpha^2 + n^2}(\alpha + i n) \\\\
&=\frac{\sinh (\pi \alpha)}{\pi} \sum_{n= -\infty}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}\,\alpha}{\alpha^2 + n^2}+i\frac{\sinh (\pi \alpha)}{\pi}\color{blue}{\overbrace{ \sum_{n= -\infty}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}\,n}{\alpha^2 + n^2}}^{=0}} \\\\
&=\frac{\sinh (\pi \alpha)}{\pi} \sum_{n= -\infty}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}\,\alpha}{\alpha^2 + n^2}
\end{align}$$

whereupon solving for the series yields

$$\sum_{n= -\infty}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}}{\alpha^2 + n^2}=\frac{\pi}{\alpha \sinh(\pi \alpha)}$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: Last expression has not $\alpha$.

Comment: @myglasses Good catch.  I've edited.  Thank you;  much appreciated.  -Mark

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Since $f$ is differentiable at $0$, its Fourier series at $0$ converges to $f(0)$.

**Complete answer:** You get

\begin{align}
1 &= \frac{\sinh (\pi \alpha)}{\pi} \sum_{n= -\infty}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}}{\alpha^2 + n^2}(\alpha + i n) \\
&= \frac{\alpha\sinh (\pi \alpha)}{\pi} \sum_{n= -\infty}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}}{\alpha^2 + n^2}\tag{$\star$}
\end{align}

hence
$$
\sum_{n= -\infty}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}}{\alpha^2 + n^2} = \frac{\pi}{\alpha \sinh(\pi \alpha)}
$$

*Note.* From the three following facts:

- if the series $\displaystyle\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}$ converges then its value is equal to $\displaystyle\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{n=-m}^m$
- the term $a_n:=\frac{(-1)^n}{\alpha^2+n^2}in$ equals $0$ for $n=0$
- $a_n=-a_{-n}$ for $n>0$

we see that
$$
\sum_{n= -\infty}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}}{\alpha^2 + n^2}(\alpha + i n) = \alpha \lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{n= -m}^m\frac{(-1)^{n}}{\alpha^2 + n^2}
$$
But this last series converges absolutely hence the order of summation doesn't matter and indeed we have
$$
\alpha \lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{n= -m}^m\frac{(-1)^{n}}{\alpha^2 + n^2} = \alpha \sum_{n= -\infty}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{\alpha^2 + n^2}
$$
This justifies $(\star)$.